# Connecting to external MySQL database from Azure Databricks with Python

Tags: python, mysql, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to an external private MySQL Database from Azure Databricks.

I have tried with sqlalchemy and pymysql:
pymysql:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='.....',
    user='.....', 
    password = "....",
    db='....')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

sqlalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@hostname:3306/database".format('user','password'))
connection = engine.connect()
```

The error code was the same:
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'IP_address' (using password: YES)"
[The external database was configured for remote access and the IPs we were trying to access it with were whitelisted]

With mysql.connector the connection was successful.

```
connection = connect(
  host=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="resource_group", key="key"),
  port=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="resource_group", key="key"),
  user=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="resource_group", key="key"),
  password=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="resource_group", key="key"),
  database="db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Question is:
Does anyone know why sqlalchemy and pymysql did not work?
Is there only certain python sql connector libraries that work in Databricks and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to connect to a MySQL database in Spark. The below image summarizes some of common approaches to connect to MySQL using Python as programming language.

**Note:** For python environment - it's recommended to use `mysql-connector-python` library.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the image and explanation. Do you have any insights as to why sqlalchemy and pymysql do not work in the Azure Databricks Environment?

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above you can use the MySQL connector natively. The code could be like this:

```
df_mysql_table = (spark.read
                        .format("mysql")
                        .option("dbtable", table_name)
                        .option("host", database_host_url)
                        .option("port", database_port)      # 3306
                        .option("database", database_name)
                        .option("user", user_name)
                        .option("password", password)
                        .option("useSSL", True)         # If MySQL Instance has "Enforce SSL connection" enabled
                        .option("sslmode", "PREFERRED" )    # other options are: DISABLED | VERIFY_CA | REQUIRED | VERIFY_IDENTITY
                        .load()
                    )
```